# vimrc "col <cs>" works but vim complains about trailing characters; colors do not work when using "color" or "colorscheme"

Tags: vim, colors

Colors work when adding `col elflord` to my .vimrc file but vim complains about trailing characters `col elflord`.  Changing the command to `color elflord` or `colorscheme elflord` gets rid of the complaint, but then colors don't work.

Comment: Glad I could help. If you think the hints might be helpful to others, please don't delete, but accept the answer by clicking on the outlined arrow next to it.

Comment: You say what solved your issue by marking the check/tick and not with an edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `:col` abbreviation expands to `:colder`, not `:colorscheme`. Typing `:col<Tab>` or `:help :col` would have told you that. I'd generally recommend to use the full command names in `.vimrc` or plugins for clarity; the abbreviations are most useful when entering commands interactively.

So, you have to investigate why the colorscheme doesn't work:

- Does it work when entered interactively? Then, there's probably another colorscheme definition in your `~/.vimrc`, or in a plugin. `:echo g:colors_name` tells you the current colorscheme.
- Does the file exist? `:echo globpath(&runtimepath, 'colors/elflord.vim')` should list the colorscheme.